# Is it possible to create instance of ClipboardEvent in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

I need to programmatically create a ClipboardEvent instance in Chrome.

But when I run the constructor:

```
new ClipboardEvent("paste", {dataType: "text/plain", data: "some data"})
```

It throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

The constructor works as intended in Firefox.

Checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/ClipboardEvent) and [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html#other-security-and-privacy-considerations) and they don't mention anything about it being illegal to create instances of ClipboardEvent.

**Is it possible to create an instance of ClipboardEvent in Chrome in any other way?** I prefer to not mock a custom ClipboardEvent when one exists.

**Update 2018-07-17:** Using the ClipboardEvent seems to work in Chrome 69.

Comment: I currently use a workaround where I create a CustomEvent and add the function evt.clipboardData.getData().

Comment: How did you get ClipboardEvent to be defined in the first place?

Comment: It is in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X, saw now that it isn't on Windows. Guess it's to early to use it at all.

Comment: How did you manage to create that evt.clipboardData.getData()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not. This is from http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

> Partial support in IE refers using a non-standard method of interacting with the clipboard. For other browsers it refers to not supporting the ClipboardEvent constructor.

[image]

Unfortunately, the only browser that properly supports the `Clipboard API` is FireFox (since 22). All other browsers (if it supports Clipboard API at all), will not support the ClipbordEvent constructor.

Comment: When I look there today, Firefox has partial support and Chrome supposedly has full support from 42 onwards. I guess it is a movable feast. But I'm using 42 and I still cannot construct a clipboard event!

Comment: Still getting this too which is odd, does anyone know if this is something that requires request of permission?

Comment: Figured it out, 'Chrome 42+ and Opera 29+ support clipboard reading/writing only when part of a user action (click, keydown, etc)' according to caniuse

Comment: What does 'Chrome 42+ and Opera 29+ support clipboard reading/writing only when part of a user action (click, keydown, etc)' mean in this case? What should be done instead of using the constructor? I can't find info on that.

Comment: But that is still possible to trigger "copy" event with  `document.execCommand("copy");` and so have usable clipboardData