# can't get "clipboard.js" to work

Tags: javascript, clipboard, clipboard.js

I can't get the [clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/) to work; I think it's a simple "misunderstanding" about how the whole thing works, since I'm not even able to get the most simple example to work properly like in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfepfnr0/)...

My specific problem is getting this to work:

HTML:

```
<button class="copyButton" 
        id="copyButtonId" 
        data-id="@item.Type" 
        data-clipboard-action="copy" 
        data-clipboard-target="#copy_@item.Type">
</button>
```

The div that should be copied is this:

```
   <div id="copy_@item.Type">
       @item.Type
       Name...: @item.Name
       Address: @item.Address
   </div>`
```

The JS is:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on("click", ".copyButton", function() {
    var clipboard = new Clipboard(".copyButton"); 
    clipboard.destroy();
  });
});
```

I'm getting into the function, but nothing is happening. I tried:

```
clipboard.copy();
```

but that just throws me an exception...

I can get the text, that I want to copy

`var id= "copy_" + $(this).attr("data-id");
   var source = ($("#" + agent).html());`

But I should be able only to work it out by using `clipboard.js`.

I can't get any examples to work, so I would be happy if someone shows me a complete example. I've really tried to understand and I may be overthinking the whole thing and making this more complicated than it is.
I don't want any workarounds, as I used that before and think this is a great js-solution... If I could just understand it :)

Every hint into the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the copier only works for input fields (or textareas) and not divs?

Comment: the example from the site works fine with div (https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/blob/master/demo/target-div.html). just when I try it, it's not

Comment: Not even when you just copy the whole thing?

Comment: thats what I put into the fiddle, it's the source code from the example...

Comment: and you're absolutely sure you've added the library? Because I don't see that in the fiddle. (apologies if you have)

Comment: I just pasted `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>` in the html of your fiddle and it copies **hello**

Comment: yeah, you're right. Got the wrong link into External Resources

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you add the right library first ;)

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.3/clipboard.min.js"></script>`

Or your local min.js

I've altered your code to this:

```
<div id="copy">
    @item.Type
    Name...: @item.Name 
    Address: @item.Address
</div>

<button class="copyButton" id="copyButtonId" data-id="@item.Type"
 data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="div#copy">Copy!</button>
```

and the js:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copyButton');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

With me it copies the div now. Let me know if it doesn't for you.

Comment: Well,it get copied with your solution, but the thing is: always the same one, thats why I need different ID's. I got a lot of different data loaded, will see if I get it from here

Comment: With me it had issues with the format of the id, so be careful with those. :)

Comment: it just selects the text it doesnt really copy it.

Comment: It selects the text AND copies it. Try pasting somewhere after clicking the button. (https://jsfiddle.net/wm9ce12m/) I made the fiddle again for you.

Comment: For those still not working please check the answer here [Illegal constructor in chrome when using clipboard API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419039/illegal-constructor-in-chrome-when-using-clipboard-api)

Answer (score 0):

Incase of API data use

```
import Clipboard from 'clipboard';
''''''
''''''
''''''
 var clipboard = new Clipboard('.class_name_of_the_div');
  clipboard.on('success', function (event) {});
  clipboard.on('error', function (evwnt) {});

data-clipboard-text={data.text}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, I haven't got time to read all but for the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard you can use

`import ClipboardJS from 'clipboard'`

and then `new ClipboardJS('.btn')`

or check if this `import Clipboard from 'clipboard'` works specially for your solution